# How to combine arrays of objects according probability in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, lodash

I have an array with 3 arrays of objects.

```
[
  [
    {
      VKORG: "3060",
      VTWEG: "AS",
      VRKME: "CX",
      LVORM: ""
    },
    {
      VKORG: "3060",
      VTWEG: "MF",
      VRKME: "CX",
      LVORM: ""
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      MEINH: "CX",
      UMREZ: "12",
      UMREN: "1"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      WERKS: "3060",
      LGORT: "0011"
    },
    {
      WERKS: "3060",
      LGORT: "HU00"
    }
  ]
]
```

So I want to combine the objects of each array within them, according the probability of combinations between then... So it should look like this:

```
[
    {
      VKORG: "3060",
      VTWEG: "AS",
      VRKME: "CX",
      LVORM: "",
      MEINH: "CX",
      UMREZ: "12 ",
      UMREN: "1 ",
      WERKS: "3060",
      LGORT: "0011"
    },
    {
      VKORG: "3060",
      VTWEG: "MF",
      VRKME: "CX",
      LVORM: "",
      MEINH: "CX",
      UMREZ: "12 ",
      UMREN: "1 ",
      WERKS: "3060",
      LGORT: "0011"
    },
    {
      VKORG: "3060",
      VTWEG: "AS",
      VRKME: "CX",
      LVORM: "",
      MEINH: "CX",
      UMREZ: "12 ",
      UMREN: "1 ",
      WERKS: "3060",
      LGORT: "HU00"
    },
    {
      VKORG: "3060",
      VTWEG: "MF",
      VRKME: "CX",
      LVORM: "",
      MEINH: "CX",
      UMREZ: "12 ",
      UMREN: "1 ",
      WERKS: "3060",
      LGORT: "HU00"
    }
  ]
};
```

How can I do that with JavaScript? I'm spending a lot of time to do that with lodash, but nothing until here.

Comment: What does "*probability of combinations*" mean and how is it calculated?

Comment: My bad... I meant that the object have to be combined according to possible probability like:

[{ ...array1[0], ...array2[0], ...array3[0] }, { ...array1[0], ...array2[0], ...array3[1] }, { ...array1[1], ...array2[0], ...array3[0] }, { ...array1[1], ...array2[0], ...array3[1] }]

Comment: Do you mean all "*possible*" combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a recursive function with `Array.flatMap()`, and `Array.map()` that combines the arrays:

```js
const cartesian = ([a, ...arrs]) => 
  arrs.length ? // if there are more arrays
    a.flatMap(o1 => cartesian(arrs) // run them through cartesian, and combine with current object
      .map(o2 => ({
        ...o1,
        ...o2
      }))
    ) : a // return the current array

const arrs = [[{ VKORG: "3060", VTWEG: "AS", VRKME: "CX", LVORM: "" }, { VKORG: "3060", VTWEG: "MF", VRKME: "CX", LVORM: "" }], [{ MEINH: "CX", UMREZ: "12", UMREN: "1" }], [{ WERKS: "3060", LGORT: "0011" }, { WERKS: "3060", LGORT: "HU00" }]]

const results = cartesian(arrs)

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a standard algorithm for a cartesian product and get joined objects as result.

```js
var data = [[{ VKORG: "3060", VTWEG: "AS", VRKME: "CX", LVORM: "" }, { VKORG: "3060", VTWEG: "MF", VRKME: "CX", LVORM: "" }], [{ MEINH: "CX", UMREZ: "12", UMREN: "1" }], [{ WERKS: "3060", LGORT: "0011" }, { WERKS: "3060", LGORT: "HU00" }]],
    result = data
        .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []))
        .map(a => Object.assign({}, ...a));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```